# ILM does support on document level in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-stack

I have created policy and applied policy on indices .
This policy allows us to set a expiry time for a document. Once the time has past, the expired documents are deleted.

Is it possible with latest version of Elasticsearch  ?

Comment: what exactly is your question ? yes ILM is supported in latest version of Elasticsearch as well if this is your question

Comment: ILM does not work at the document level, but on the index level.

Comment: And it is unlikely to change: Deleting individual documents is quite expensive; deleting the entire index is very cheap in comparison. Ideally you can find a way not to require deleting (lots of) individual documents.

Comment: I want set ILM on document level or individual document. if it possible please share any any link or documents  .

Comment: I think you got confused. ILM works on index level and not on documents. 
This is true for opensearch as well as for ElasticSearch

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know ILM deletes the entire index and criteria will be the duration of days since the index has been created. If you need to delete a specific document I feel you will need to leverage API to implement this. You can setup a cronjob which uses the below script to delete a specific doc.

```
curl -k -X POST "https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@localhost:9200/test/_delete_by_query?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "lt": "now-30d"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
 }
```

Reference : https://discuss.elastic.co/t/automatically-delete-older-documents/247078/9